# Ignore mysql row based on column value

Tags: mysql

I have a phpbb forum using mysql databases. The users are identified by "user_id." However, they have multiple groups. Users will either be in the "human" (9) or "zombie" (8) group. However, they will always be in the "registered" (2) group. This creates a table that looks like this:

[image: mysql table]

Three databases are used in total to form a new table.

```
SELECT phpbb_users.user_id 'ID',
IF( phpbb_user_group.group_id =9,  'Human', IF( phpbb_user_group.group_id =8,  'Zombie', '')) AS Team,

IF( phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_oz =1,  'Yes',  ' ' ) AS OZ,
phpbb_users.username 'Player', phpbb_users.user_email 'E-mail',
IF( phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_share_phonenum =1, phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_phone_number,  ' ' ) AS Phone,
phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_code 'Tag Code',
phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_student_id 'Student ID', phpbb_users.starve 'Time Remaining (in hours)'
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data, phpbb_users, phpbb_user_group
WHERE phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id = phpbb_users.user_id
AND phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id = phpbb_user_group.user_id
LIMIT 0 , 300
```

I need all the rows with blank fields under "Team" (which are the result of the "registered" group) removed from the result set. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `HAVING` clause to the end of your `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
WHERE phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id = phpbb_users.user_id
AND phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id = phpbb_user_group.user_id
HAVING Team <> ''
LIMIT 0 , 300
```

The `HAVING` clause will make **MySQL** to do another filtering pass on the query result (including any aggregate results) and then discards those records not matching the `HAVING` clause.

You can also have several conditions in the `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
HAVING Team <> '' and Player <> 'First Last'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm. This has made a small snag, however. I have a moderator that is of both the human and the zombie teams. I need him to not appear on the list. I tried "HAVING Player <> 'First Last'" but the having statement doesn't work when there are 2 of them.

Comment: Did you try HAVING Team <> '' and Player <> 'First Last'  ?